# OpenCV and VisualStudio 2010 dll problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

Hi everyone I would like to try the openCV library but I have some problems setting up the environment.

From the property Manager I created a new sheet and set:

**VC++ Directories :** 
- Include Directories: $(OPENCV_DIR)\build\x86\vc10\bin and $(OPENCV2_DIR)\build\include
- Library Directories: $(OPENCV2_DIR)\build\x86\vc10\lib;

**C/C++ :**
- Additional Includes Directories: $(OPENCV2_DIR)\include;

**Linker:**

> opencv_calib3d244d.lib opencv_contrib244d.lib opencv_core244d.lib
>   opencv_features2d244d.lib opencv_flann244d.lib opencv_gpu244d.lib
>   opencv_haartraining_engined.lib opencv_highgui244d.lib
>   opencv_imgproc244d.lib opencv_legacy244d.lib opencv_ml244d.lib
>   opencv_nonfree244d.lib opencv_objdetect244d.lib opencv_photo244d.lib
>   opencv_stitching244d.lib opencv_ts244d.lib opencv_video244d.lib
>   opencv_videostab244d.lib

-Additional Library Directories: $(OPENCV2_DIR)\libs

I can compile but i can't execute the program because I get an error opencv_core242.dll is missing.

Where's my error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I get an error opencv_core242.dll is missing"

if you linked against the  libs in opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib (your compiler/linker settings look ok),

you'll have to append

opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin

to your PATH environment variable, so your exe can find the dlls at runtime.

Comment: You mean the OPENCV2_DIR path? i did it:
C:\devel\OpenCV-2.4.4\opencv is it correct?

Comment: PATH=more\other\stuff;C:\devel\OpenCV-2.4.4\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin